# fork() and pipe()

Tags: c, fork, pipe

I need help with this sample application. When I run it, it gets stuck after the child process prints "Child sending!".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define INPUT 0
#define OUTPUT 1
int main()
{
    int fd1[2];
    int fd2[2];
    int pid;
    if (pipe(fd1) < 0)
        exit(1);
    if (pipe(fd2) < 0)
        exit(1);
    if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(fd1[INPUT]);
        close(fd2[OUTPUT]);
        char *str = "Hello World!";
        printf("Child sending!\n");
        write(fd1[OUTPUT], str, strlen(str));
        char *bufferc = (char *)malloc(1000);
        char *readbufferc = (char *)malloc(80);
        int rdc;
        int gotdata = 0;
        while (gotdata == 0)
             while ((rdc = read(fd2[INPUT], readbufferc, sizeof(readbufferc))) > 0)
             {
               strncat(bufferc,readbufferc,rdc);
               gotdata = 1;
             }
        printf("Child received: %s",bufferc);
        free(readbufferc);
        free(bufferc);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        close(fd1[OUTPUT]);
        close(fd2[INPUT]);
        int rd;
        char *buffer = (char *)malloc(1000);
        char *readbuffer = (char *)malloc(80);
        int gd = 0;
        while (gd == 0)
             while ((rd = read(fd1[INPUT],readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer))) > 0)
             {
               strncat(buffer, readbuffer,rd);
               gd = 1;
             }
        printf("Parent received: %s\n",buffer);
        free(readbuffer);
        printf("Parent sending!");
        write(fd2[OUTPUT], buffer, strlen(buffer));
        free(buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

On a side note, is there a way to debug when I use [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)), because GDB automatically goes to the parent process?

Comment: You operate on `fd2` without ever also calling `pipe(fd2)`.  (And as these are pairs of fds, you might call them `pipe1` and `pipe2`).

Comment: Thanks I added that and it still got stuck after "Child sending!"

Comment: Also: `sizeof(readbuffer)` will not evaluate to 80.  It will evaluate to `sizeof(char *)`.  `sizeof()` only returns what you expect when applied to an actual array.  Please get a better example of `pipe()` [here](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html).

Comment: Related: *[What is fork and pipe in C and can they be used in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812891/fork-and-pipes-in-c#4812891)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the child writes to the parent, it must close the write end of the pipe so the parent knows it has reached EOF.

Answer (score 1):

Several things wrong:

- `fd2` is just never initialized.
- The parent will never exit this:

  ```
  while ((rd = read(fd1[INPUT],readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer))) > 0)
  {
      strncat(buffer, readbuffer,rd);
      gd = 1;
  }
  ```

If there is no data to read, read will block and just not return. The only thing that would make it exit is if the connection was closed and the child doesn't close it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many bugs in your code. Why are you using fd2 without initializing it? Remove it.

Now it's stuck at "Child sending", because pipe read is a blocking call and you are putting it in a *while* loop which will never return. Please refer to the [man page of pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). 
If you want to break that *while* loop, close all write ends of that pipe.

Also to debug a child process, use the GDB command `follow-fork-mode` as child before call to fork() while debugging.

Comment: thanks for the follow-fork-mode command. will definitely come in handy

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `read()` in the expectation that if there is nothing to read, it will return with zero bytes read. However, what you are seeing is because `read()` is waiting for some data before returning. To address this, you need to do one of two things:

- set your socket to do [non-blocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O) reads (not recommended)
- use [`select()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) or `poll()` to see whether there is some data to read before you read it

Also, several other points:

- [don't cast the returns from `malloc()`](http://c-faq.com/malloc/mallocnocast.html)
- check that `malloc()` does not return `NULL`
- replace the whole `gotdata` thing with a `break` instruction