# What is fork and pipe in C and can they be used in C++?

Tags: c++, c

What is `fork` and what is `pipe`?
What could be some scenarios explaining why their use is necessary?
What are the differences between `fork` and `pipe` in C?
Can we use them in C++?

I need to know this is because I want to implement a program in C++ which can access live video input, convert its format and write it to a file.
What would be the best approach for this?

I have used [x264](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X264) for this. So far I have implemented the part of conversion on a file format.
Now I have to implement it on a live stream.
Is it a good idea to use pipes? Capture video in another process and feed it to the other?

Comment: Can somebody tell me what is the alternative for "unistd.h" in VC++

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/12/07/introducing-pipes-justin-van-patten.aspx for answer

Comment: What context for fork and pipe? The concept? The literal functions fork() and pipe()? fork() and pipe() in x264? fork() and pipe() in the [C standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) (libc)? fork() and pipe() in the [C POSIX library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library)?

Comment: Tag [fork](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fork/info): *"The fork() function is the Unix/Linux/POSIX way of creating a new (child) process by duplicating the calling (parent) process."*

Comment: Tag [pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pipe/info): *"A pipe is created with the POSIX pipe() function (from <unistd.h>)."*

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A pipe is a mechanism for interprocess communication. Data written to the pipe by one process can be read by another process. The primitive for creating a pipe is the [pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) function (from header file *[unistd.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h)* in the [C POSIX library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_POSIX_library)). This creates both the reading and writing ends of the pipe.

It is not very useful for a single process to use a pipe to talk to itself. In typical use, a process creates a pipe just before it `forks` one or more child processes. The pipe is then used for communication either between the parent or child processes, or between two sibling processes.

A familiar example of this kind of communication can be seen in all operating system shells. When you type a command at the shell, it will spawn the executable represented by that command with a call to `fork`. A pipe is opened to the new child process and its output is read and printed by the shell.

[This page](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Creating-a-Pipe.html#Creating-a-Pipe) has a full example of the `fork` and `pipe` functions. For your convenience, the code is reproduced below:

```
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 /* Read characters from the pipe and echo them to stdout. */

 void
 read_from_pipe (int file)
 {
   FILE *stream;
   int c;
   stream = fdopen (file, "r");
   while ((c = fgetc (stream)) != EOF)
     putchar (c);
   fclose (stream);
 }

 /* Write some random text to the pipe. */

 void
 write_to_pipe (int file)
 {
   FILE *stream;
   stream = fdopen (file, "w");
   fprintf (stream, "hello, world!\n");
   fprintf (stream, "goodbye, world!\n");
   fclose (stream);
 }

 int
 main (void)
 {
   pid_t pid;
   int mypipe[2];

   /* Create the pipe. */
   if (pipe (mypipe))
     {
       fprintf (stderr, "Pipe failed.\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

   /* Create the child process. */
   pid = fork ();
   if (pid == (pid_t) 0)
     {
       /* This is the child process.
          Close other end first. */
       close (mypipe[1]);
       read_from_pipe (mypipe[0]);
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
   else if (pid < (pid_t) 0)
     {
       /* The fork failed. */
       fprintf (stderr, "Fork failed.\n");
       return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
   else
     {
       /* This is the parent process.
          Close other end first. */
       close (mypipe[0]);
       write_to_pipe (mypipe[1]);
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
     }
 }
```

Just like other C functions you can use both `fork` and `pipe` in C++.

Comment: There is at least one common case where a pipe is useful within one process: you can use it to convert signals to `select()` wakeups.

Comment: Thanks Vijay for the thorough response. It was exactly what i needed

Comment: One problem! I am trying to do this in VC++, it gives the error "Cannot find unistd.h" why is it so? Any remedies for this?

Comment: @nightWatcher: VC++ won't have unistd.h. The "uni" is for Unix. The header is for Unix Standard functions. In Windows you will need to use the Windows functions. You might want a mailslot or a pipe. But in Windows you need to use CreatePipe(). Read up on "interprocess communication" on MSDN.

Comment: @Zan thanx alot...i have found a good link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/12/07/introducing-pipes-justin-van-patten.aspx

Answer (score 6):

There are [standard input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_input_(stdin)) and [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) for common input and output.

A common style is like this:

```
input -> process -> output
```

But with pipe, it becomes:

```
input -> process1 -> (tmp_output) -> (tmp-input) -> process2 -> output
```

`pipe` is the function that returns the two temporary `tmp-input` and `tmp-output`, i.e., `fd[0]` and `fd[1]`.