# C++ How To Create/Use Pipe and Fork?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I need to learn how to create a `pipe` and use `fork`, and also how to write to a `pipe` and `read`, in VC++ 2010.

Are there any tutorials on how to do that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but... pipe and fork are Posix system calls, while VC++ is a Microsoft Windows IDE and framework... Why would you specifically ask for instructions for this one?

Comment: So you telling me I can't create pipe and use fork in vc++ 2010 Win32? D:

Comment: What you're asking here is how to make orange juice from apples. It won't work.

Comment: In theory you can create a posix executable and run it under SFU/SUA...

Answer (score 2):

This question is already answered in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812891/fork-and-pipes-in-c). 
Quoting verbatim from the same answer

> A pipe is a mechanism for interprocess communication. Data written to the pipe by one process can be read by another process. The primitive for creating a pipe is the pipe function. This creates both the reading and writing ends of the pipe. It is not very useful for a single process to use a pipe to talk to itself. In typical use, a process creates a pipe just before it forks one or more child processes. The pipe is then used for communication either between the parent or child processes, or between two sibling processes. A familiar example of this kind of communication can be seen in all operating system shells. When you type a command at the shell, it will spawn the executable represented by that command with a call to fork. A pipe is opened to the new child process and its output is read and printed by the shell. This page has a full example of the fork and pipe functions...