# Pipe between C++ program and a cmd console

Tags: c++, cmd, named-pipes

I made a [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++) program which spawns a command line and forwards commands to it. At the moment I'm sending the output of the cmd console to a file, and I'm reading it in my C++ program. But I want to make this work with pipes.

Is it possible to write to a named pipe from the Windows cmd line? I haven't found anything significant on this subject.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_popen` for this, it's included in the C stdlib, so it should work on Windows.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/popen.html

You can pass the name of the second executable to the popen call in the first program.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminology confuses me a bit - but I'm assuming that you are using VC (Visual C++)

I found this answer (to a similar question) that better explains how pipes and forks work ([Well explained pipes examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812891/fork-and-pipes-in-c))