# Type channels for format specifiers

Tags: c, format-specifiers

My teacher usually says there is a pipe channel for each format specifier in printf. That is, there is a pipe channel for %d, one for %f and so on. He says, expressions corresponding to each format specifier are evaluated and inserted in its pipe and finally taken from it. He adds, at least in gcc, filling of the pipes (argument evaluation) is done right-to-left and emptying of the pipes (printing the values) is done left-to-right.

**What is this concept of pipe channels for format specifiers?** I couldn't see it anywhere other than the possibly related pipe() function. The following is a related question: [fork() and pipes() in c](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4812963/8653606).

Quoting from an answer to that question,

> A pipe is a mechanism for interprocess communication. Data written to the pipe by one process can be read by another process. The primitive for creating a pipe is the pipe() function. This creates both the reading and writing ends of the pipe.

Is the compiler using a piping mechanism for executing printf statement this way? Is this related to piping in linux?

Comment: I don't think he meant pipes in the sense of Unix pipes. That would be _too_ weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just about everything your instructor said is wrong.  I have never heard the terms "type channel" or "pipe channel" having anything to do with C programming.

Argument passing typically involves the function call stack, and perhaps processor registers.  It involves nothing like Unix pipes.

It is often the case that floating-point arguments are passed using different registers than integers.  This can lead to particular confusion when you have mismatches between printf specifiers and their arguments (e.g. `%d` versus `%f`).  Perhaps that's what your instructor was trying to explain.

It is also not true (or at least highly misleading) to suggest that there is any right-to-left or left-to-right ordering in the evaluation or consumption of function arguments.  For example, if you were to write

```
printf("a and b returned %d and %d\n", a(), b());
```

this would indeed print out the return values of functions `a()` and `b()`, but you would have no way of knowing which of the two functions got called first.  The compiler might do it in either order.

There is a special, rarely-used feature in many versions of `printf` that allows you to use numbers to match up printf format specifiers with their arguments.  You can read a bit about this in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Parameter_field) (where they call it the "parameter field").  But I doubt your instructor was talking about that.

Comment: Yes, the positional `n$` feature is obscure (as in not very well known at all), even though it is widely supported. In fact, it turns out it is even supported by [Microsoft C](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/printf-p-positional-parameters), if you use `_printf_p()` instead of `printf()` (although you must then provide the position information for every format specifier). The only place I recall seeing this positional parameter feature used is in localization/multilanguage support, where it helps a lot, and is probably the reason why the feature exists in the first place.

Comment: He is likely talking about registers. 'Pipe' may be an informal word he uses to avoid confusing students. But he keeps on using that word which got me confused :)  .
And your guess is right. He is trying to explain unspecified and/or undefined  behaviour when there is an argument mismatch or multiple updation of the same object in a printf statement. Thank you