# Download zip file from an API and send it as a response from another API using axios

Tags: node.js, api, rest, axios, zip

I have 2 Node REST APIs. *API A* generates a **.zip file** and sends it as a response (using `sendFile()`) and *API B* (gateway) has to retrieve this zip file from *API A* and send it as a response too (it is kind of nesting the responses).

In order to make this happen, *API B* uses `axios` to make the `GET` request to obtain the .zip.
So far I am able to generate this file and download it from API A but I am having trouble handling the download from API B

I read dozens of Stack Overflow questions and in almost every example the client after making a request creates (or receives in `responseType`) a **BLOB** object which then gets downloaded to the user. This does not solve this problem because this is not the browser and I need to keep nesting the zip file in the response.

Also, NodeJS does not have blob objects so I don't know if I should get the zip as **'arraybuffer'**, **'stream'** or something else to send it in the response.

```
exports.getZip = (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get('http://someApi.com', { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data); // Buffer Data!
                res.status(201).sendFile(response.data); // ???
            })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are working between microservices/APIs you cannot receive a **blob** object or the zip file directly as if this was a browser. One solution is to specify the response type as **'stream'** and `pipe` the data from the response of API A to the response of API B. (could be solved with '*arraybuffer*' too but with a different logic)

```
exports.getZip = (req, res, next) => {
    axios.get('http://someApi.com', { responseType: 'stream' })
            .then(response => {
                // The response will give you the zip file 
                response.data.pipe(res);
            })
}
```

A similar example can be found on the  [axios docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig)

***(A pipe is a mechanism for interprocess communication. Data written to the pipe by one process can be read by another process. The output of a process will be the input of another process [Read more about piping here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812891/fork-and-pipes-in-c))*